# How to create a video from a series of images with different frame rate?

Tags: ffmpeg

I create two videos as

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -i a%03d.exr -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv444p10le out1.mp4
ffmpeg -r 25 -i a%03d.exr -c:v libx264 -vf reverse,fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv444p10le out2.mp4
```

and concat two videos.

Is it possible to run these commands in a single one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i a%03d.exr -framerate 25 -i a%03d.exr -filter_complex "[0]fps=25[v0];[1]reverse[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,format=yuv444p10le[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```